# Integrating Gt-pay to my website using php

Tags: javascript, php

I an currently working online application system using php, form payment has to be done on the system. i need help on how to integrate gtpay using php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write code for you. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Definitely needs more information on what you tried, what errors you received etc, share code and other things.